# Possible to add multiple layers to GeoServer in one step?

Tags: geoserver

Possible to add multiple layers to GeoServer in one step through the admin UI?

[image]

The immediate answer seems to be "no" but maybe I'm overlooking another way of doing this?

Comment: I'm using GeoServer 2.12.3

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through adding a GeoServer Importer Extension: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/importer/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way of creating batches of layers through the UI, but the REST API works really well for doing things in batches. All you need is cURL (https://curl.haxx.se/) installed and you can submit requests which can achieve most of what you can do through the UI but in a programmatic way.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible you can use layer group and FOA you have to create layer group then select the add layer here you can select as much as you want